# Translation of some paper?

Tags: reference-request

I am painfully trying to read this paper by H. Poincaré:

> Sur les Equations Linéaires aux Différentielles Ordinaires et aux Différences Finies

[Link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2369270)

Unfortunately this is in French, which I studied many, many years ago and have now almost forgotten...

> *Are there repositories or other sources with translation of papers in English?*

I know that some Russian papers (and also books) have been translated in English during Cold War period, but I am not aware of something like this for other languages...

Comment: He passed away before the Cold War was even thought of. Check the Mathematics stack as they may know - lots of the scientists worked in several languages.

Comment: An academic librarian might be able to help.

Comment: Why are you trying to read Poincare? Can't you find a modern treatment of the subject?

Comment: @MoisheKohan There are many different possible reasons for reading this paper. Often these old papers include subtleties overlooked in newer developments. Or perhaps the OP is a historian and not interested in "a modern treatment of the subject"?

Comment: @Theoretician: For a historian of math, it would be reasonable. For math itself: I have read many original works of Poincare on complex analysis and topology. There was nothing there that one cannot find in subsequent (and much better written) papers by others. I do not see a reason for his paper on linear ODEs to be any different.

Comment: is using a translation software/tool out of the question? It will not be perfect, but give you at least some insight